# Python, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'

Tags: python, module, pytube

I am getting an error. I downloaded the pytube module, but it didn't solve this error.

[image]

```
from pytube import Youtube

yt = Youtube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsP7OUPet7s');

yt.streams.first().download();
```

```
Error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'
```

Comment: pip install pytube!?

Comment: I tried but it didn't improve

Comment: use pip install pytube3 that might help